# Invoking nvcc.exe using CreateProcess

Tags: winapi, cuda, createprocess, nvcc

We currently use a mock JIT compiler for CUDA, where nvcc.exe is invoked on some files and the resulting .ptx files are generated.

```
bool executeWindowsProcess(ofstream &logFF) {

    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );

    char cmd[] = "\"C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\\CUDA\\v5.0\\bin\\nvcc.exe\"";
    char args[] = "\"C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\\CUDA\\v5.0\\bin\\nvcc.exe\" --ptx --machine 32 -arch=sm_30 -o C:\\Users\\Yutong\\GOODKERNELCOMPILED.ptx --use_fast_math C:\\Users\\Yutong\\tempkernel.cu";

    logFF << cmd << endl;
    logFF << args << endl;

    CreateProcess(cmd, args, NULL, NULL, false, CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi); 

    logFF << GetLastError() << endl;

    WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);

    logFF << GetLastError() << endl;

    CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
    CloseHandle( pi.hThread );

    return true;
}
```

The first GetLastError() returns 123, which seems to indicate that nvcc.exe isn't invoked at all. Setting cmd[] to something like notepad.exe (which is in C:/Windows/System32/notepad.exe) works fine. I've asked some people, and it seems that:

1. My app is deployed for 32-bit Windows
2. nvcc.exe is located in C:/Program Files/..../ which is a 64-bit directory, and CreateProcess doesn't seem to be able to invoke executables in directories it doesn't have permission for.

PS, we used to use system() to invoke the JIT compiler, but system() launches an external terminal window (we're writing a GUI) and is generally not recommended.

Comment: Were you meaning to ask a question here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetLastError()` only has meaning when an actual error occurs.  You are not checking the return value of `CreateProcess()` to make sure an error actually occurred before then calling `GetLastError()` to retrieve it.  You need to do so, eg:

```
bool executeWindowsProcess(ofstream &logFF)
{
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );

    char cmd[] = "\"C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\\CUDA\\v5.0\\bin\\nvcc.exe\"";
    char args[] = "\"C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\\CUDA\\v5.0\\bin\\nvcc.exe\" --ptx --machine 32 -arch=sm_30 -o C:\\Users\\Yutong\\GOODKERNELCOMPILED.ptx --use_fast_math C:\\Users\\Yutong\\tempkernel.cu";

    logFF << cmd << endl;
    logFF << args << endl;

    if (!CreateProcess(cmd, args, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
    {
        logFF << GetLastError() << endl;
        return false;
    }

    logFF << "Running" << endl;

    WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);

    logFF << "Terminated" << endl;

    CloseHandle( pi.hThread );
    CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );

    return true;
}
```

With that said, error 123 is `ERROR_INVALID_NAME` ("The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.").  Since you are trying to invoke a command-line, I suggest you set the `lpApplicationName` parameter of `CreateProcess()` to NULL and just use the `lpCommandLine` parameter by itself, eg:

```
bool executeWindowsProcess(ofstream &logFF)
{
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );

    char args[] = "\"C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\\CUDA\\v5.0\\bin\\nvcc.exe\" --ptx --machine 32 -arch=sm_30 -o C:\\Users\\Yutong\\GOODKERNELCOMPILED.ptx --use_fast_math C:\\Users\\Yutong\\tempkernel.cu";

    logFF << args << endl;

    if (!CreateProcessA(NULL, args, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
    {
        logFF << GetLastError() << endl;
        return false;
    }

    logFF << "Running" << endl;

    WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);

    logFF << "Terminated" << endl;

    CloseHandle( pi.hThread );
    CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Hi this is a great answer! It seems that indeed moving everything to the command line works. Part of our workflow also pipes everything to a log file via "2>" which breaks things - not sure how to deal with this. 


\"C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\\CUDA\\v5.0\\bin\\nvcc.exe\" --ptx --machine 32 -arch=sm_30 -o C:\\Users\\Yutong\\GOODKERNELCOMPILED.ptx --use_fast_math C:\\Users\\Yutong\\tempkernel.cu 2> log.txt

Comment: You cannot use command-line piping with `CreateProcess()` like that. You will have to either 1) create your own STDOUT handle via `CreatePipe()` and give it to `CreateProcess()`, then manually read nvcc's output and write it to file yourself, or 2) don't have `CreateProcess()` call nvcc.exe directly, have it call cmd.exe instead, passing it the `/C` parameter to specify the complete command line for it to execute, including piping. Use the `%COMSPEC%` environment variable to locate the full path to cmd.exe.

Comment: unfortunately the CMD /C option doesn't work, I don't think the '>' character is even allowed. I'm looking up how to do pipes right now (but its looking quite ugly).

Comment: @proteneer: yes, you can use the `>` character with cmd.exe. I just tested it, it worked fine. I was able to redirect output to a .txt file using `"<full path to>\cmd.exe" /C <command line> > log.txt`. In fact, it is specifically because it is going through cmd.exe that command-line redirection can be used at all, because `>` is part of the command processor.

Comment: thanks! I got it working =) I was being lazy and just passing in %COMPSPEC% as opposed to fully qualifying (expanding out) the path to cmd

Comment: @proteneer: yes, you have to expand out `%COMSPEC%` first.

Comment: I had been compiling forever with `lpApplicationName` set and it worked fine. It stopped working with VS19. Set it to `NULL` and all is good! Thanks.