# Failing to open a chrome browser via CreateProcess API

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am trying to open a chrome browser via CreateProcess API. I was not able to do so.

I tried to do like this:

```
    string commandLine = "\"C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe\"";
    commandLine += " -- ";
    commandLine += pURLinfo->szURL;
    CreateProcess(commandLine.c_str(), NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE,
              CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL, &startupInfo, &processInformation);
```

CreateProcess returned error 123. 
    Perhaps there is another way to open it. (i wasn't talking about ShellExecute).

Update: My code now looks like this and still i cannot run chrome.

```
STARTUPINFOA si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

// Start the child process. 
if (!CreateProcessA("C:\\Program Files(x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe",     // No module name (use command line)
    NULL,
    NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
    NULL,           // Thread handle not inhberitable
    FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
    0,              // No creation flags
    NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
    NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
    &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
    &pi)           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
    )
{
    printf("CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError());
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Here you go https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx aaaand it's ERROR_INVALID_NAME. I'm sure you know what to do.

Comment: Error 123 is ERROR_INVALID_NAME ("The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect."). Be sure that you'll provide correct path.

Comment: Btw, can be dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15469666/invoking-nvcc-exe-using-createprocess

Comment: Not exactly. I was only asking about chrome

Comment: with the update it returns now error code 3. I specifically copied that path of chrome. I cannot understand why it cannot run from there

Comment: Try to add a space here: Program Files(x86) --> Program Files (x86)

Comment: Thanks it was really the space issue. Really annoying.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove unneeded quotes from command line

```
string commandLine = "C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe";
```